# How to fit a gumshield it some teeth are missing

Tags: boxing, protective-equipment

I have just brought a gumshield for boxing. I have four front teeth missing. Do I fit the gumshield with false teeth in or out to take the shape correctly?

Comment: Why would you ask strangers on the Internet instead of your dentist?...

Comment: I would say fit it how you plan to be fighting.

Comment: deep sigh... every webpage is the same NO DEFINITIVE ANSWER: I have no teeth whatsoever -English word spelled correctly- and I've search high and low for a "GUM SHIELD" no teeth just a gum.. is there an answer? NO! I give up!

Answer (score 2):

Based on [this answer](http://forums.sherdog.com/forums/f16/mouthguard-missing-teeth-983208/), it looks like the recommendation is to mold it without false teeth in. The answer [is different](http://mouthguards.opro.com/custom-faqs) for children, whose teeth are likely to grow back.

Answer (score 2):

This seems pretty straight forward.  If you plan to wear your prosthetic while using the mouthguard, mold it with the prosthetic in place.

If you plan on using the mouthguard without your prosthetic, mold it without the prosthetic in place.

If you are looking for advice on whether to wear your prosthetic, or not, you should consult your dentist. Your dental appliance is not designed to resist the stress of repeated blunt force trauma. Your dentist will almost certainly suggest not wearing it with the mouthguard.