# Gum Shield for someone with false teeth

Tags: boxing

Can anyone tell me if there is a gum shield for someone who has false teeth? I used to do quite a lot of boxing when I was younger, but now I have false teeth and I want to get back in shape again. I'm 43 years old but I'm still as fit as most 20 year olds.

Can anyone help ???

Comment: You might find some answers at http://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/5504/how-to-fit-a-gumshield-it-some-teeth-are-missing/5505#5505

Comment: Talk to your dentist; they are the experts when it comes to teeth!

Comment: Thanks for help on gum guards dentures, been self conscious about asking in a gym, lost most of my top teeth in an accident, n only have four bottoms and partial plate, won't stop me scrapping anyways, csbt keep an angry dog down.. 

Answer (score 3):

Looking online it seems that you may have to go with a [custom mouthguard](https://www.healthtap.com/user_questions/638791-are-there-any-safe-mouth-guards-for-false-teeth).

You should probably consult with your dentist and your doctor around the pros and cons of keeping your dentures in while sparring. The last thing you would want is to have your false teeth break off in your mouth, both from a safety and a cost perspective. I could imagine an absolute worst-case where you have full dentures being knocked off your gums and floating freely in your mouth....

Answer (score 2):

I lost a tooth playing rugby as a teenager.

There is a dental school near where I work, so I signed up to be a guinea pig for the students and in return I got a custom gum shield made for doing judo competitions (as well as regular check ups)

A custom made one is the best solution in my opinion,very comfortable and snug.

Any dentist should be able to make one for you.

Answer (score 0):

when you put your mouth guard in hot water it becomes pliable in the inside and then you just shape it to your gums or dentures, i suggest not wearing dentures because any impact can drive the sharp edges (I have partial bridges) into your gums and it REALLY hurts.

Comment: I am afraid that this does not answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

There’s enough there to answer the question:

1. Get a custom mouth guard (try gladiator elite)
2. Fit it to go directly on your gums (dentures removed at fitting).
3. Wear it directly on your gums (dentures removed) when engaging in martial arts
4. Consult your dentist.

“Marquis of Queensberrry Rules! Marquis of Queensberrry Rules!“