# Do you take out full dentures when fighting or sparring?

Tags: sparring, safety

If you have dentures for all your teeth, do you fit/make the mouthguard over/on your dentures or over your gums? Meaning you take out the dentures when you spar or fight.

I know that there are fighters with a few false teeth and they have them either drilled in or out when they fight. But I'm talking about those dentures that you take out at night. Because it seems safer to only wear a mouthguard over the gums but I might be wrong. Hope someone can help.

Answer (score 1):

As per the answer to [I have full dentures top and bottom... should I fit my mouthguard to my dentures or directly to my gums?](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/q/5891/1780), and to a degree the answers at [How to fit a gumshield it some teeth are missing](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/5504/how-to-fit-a-gumshield-it-some-teeth-are-missing), you will want to consult with your dentist, but the general consensus is that you probably do not want to wear your dentures into the fight as there is a high risk of them being dislodged and/or breaking, even with a mouthguard.